# How to store a column from my dataframe in a numpy array?

Tags: pandas, numpy

```
// Dataframe with one column named as 'Age' consisting of float value
Real_Madrid=pd.read_csv('E:\Pyhton codes\data\data.csv')
clean_team_dataframe(Real_Madrid,str='Real Madrid')

// the maximum value in age column is 32.0
rm_age=np.array(Real_Madrid['Age'])
rm_age.max()
out:45
```

The values stored in numpy array are not same as the value in Real_Madrid['Age']

Comment: Have you tried using [pandas.Series.to_numpy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html)?

Comment: temp=pd.Series(Real_Madrid['Age'])   
    rm_age=temp.to_numpy(dtype='float32')
      rm_age.max()   //my notrebook is showing the error:'Series' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'

Comment: Depending on which pandas version you have, you can do `Series.values` or `Series.to_numpy()`. The latter is available only from pandas version 0.24.0.

Comment: I think the method clean_team_dataframe which you have written that could be the reason, for unmatched values, please cross-check that method, if possible please share some screenshots for better understanding, like clean_team_dataframe method implementation or current result of Real_Madrid['Age'] and the original output.